# Running a command and putting output in TextView?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Basically, I am writing an app and I'm trying to do a `cat` on a file. I have a very basic UI that consists of a button and a TextView. When I click on that button, I want to execute the command and display the output on the screen (I believe TextView is the best way to do this?). I know how to make it display a set text, but I need it to display text on what I'm running `cat` on. Thanks in advance!

Edit: Code is...

```
package com.android.test;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Root3Activity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

  Button getVoltagesButton;
  TextView voltages;

  protected static final String get_voltages = "cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/vdd_levels_havs";

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.main);
      String currentVoltages = null;

      getVoltagesButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
      getVoltagesButton.setOnClickListener(VoltageListener);
      voltages = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);

  }

  private OnClickListener VoltageListener = new OnClickListener()
  {
    public void onClick (View v) {
      try {
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec(get_voltages);
        //what goes here??
      } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
  };
}
```

Comment: Can you please post your code of running cat?

Comment: It's up, but it formatted itself weird. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

The `exec()` method you are using to run `cat` returns a [Process](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Process.html) object. The Process object has a method called [getInputStream()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Process.html#getInputStream%28%29). I think you can use that to get an input stream which you can use to get the standart output. From that, you can write the values read from the input stream to your text view.

Comment: If I change my code to this...

`Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(get_voltages);  
           DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(p.getOutputStream());`

I know I'm on the right path, I just don't know how to send this information to a TextView (don't want to use a Toast since this information needs to stay on the screen). Any idea?

Comment: Note that *no* shell commands are part of the SDK.  You should use the standard Java IO APIs to read the file.  This will be a ton more efficient than executing a sub-command, too.

Answer (score 0):

```
private static final String get_voltages = "/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/vdd_levels_havs";

private final String getCurrentValue() throws IOException{
File yourFile = new File(get_voltages);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(yourFile));
String line, vm = "";

while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    vm = line;
    break;
}
return vm;
}
```

This should read the file and in this case return the last line. If the file has more than one line you could use a StringBuilder sB. Then in the while loop you can just use sb.append(line); Then with the return set it to your textview. Also I sent you a private message on XDA about help you with this project but for some reason it would not go through. Love you scripts for HTC Evo I will help if I can.

Comment: This still isn't working for me, unfortunately. And I did get your PM, I responded. Just send me an email instead if XDA is being dumb, click on my name here, my email is listed. Thanks again!